# Writing conditional statements in c as (value == variable) instead of (variable == value)

Tags: c, coding-style

I have observed that a lot of coders while writing a condition statement do something like this

```
if(NULL == Ptr){

//Some code

}
```

instead of `if(Ptr == NULL){ //some code ...`

What is a reason behind this coding practice? I belive that it does not change the meaning of the statement in anyway, so why write like this?

Please point me out if I am making a blunder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual reason for doing this, is so if the code is mistakenly written as

```
if(NULL = Ptr){

//Some code

}
```

It will be a compile error, rather than just a semantic error.

As ouah and Bo Persson point out, this is largely unnecessary, as modern compilers have reintegrated much of the semantic checking that historically was delegated to a separate `lint` program.

`gcc -Wall -Wextra` will tell you the line looks fishy:

```
test.c:3:2: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

I don't consider it *semantically wrong* as ouah does, comparison being commutative (even when implemented by subtraction and test for non-zero). But it does make the code less *readable*, if you intend to read it aloud, perhaps to a review group.

```
If NULL is-equal-to pointer then 
    Block comment (some code) end-Block
```

It reads funny this way. Whereas

```
If pointer is-equal-to NULL ...
```

is smoother to the ear.

Comment: The thing is that the compiler will tell you about the problem either way (unlike some compilers from the 1980's).

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate that. Sorry for the duplication of the question. But honestly I dint find it in my search.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(NULL == Ptr)
```

is equivalent to

```
if(Ptr == NULL)
```

as the `==` operator is commutative. The idea of this form is to trigger a compiler error if the programmer incorrectly wrote `NULL = Ptr` when he meant `NULL == Ptr`.

The problem with this approach is IMHO it makes the code less readable and it is semantically incorrect because you want to compare `Ptr` to `NULL` and not the opposite.

Moreover any decent compiler with warnings enabled will trigger a warning with `if (Ptr = NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

It does the same thing, but I find it confusing, since to be consistent, you also need to write

```
 if (0 > a)
```

instead of

```
 if (a < 0)
```

which is often confusing, since there is a document or something describing that "a must be less than zero", not "zero must be more than a".